# Algorithm to count most repeated element;

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a tree of structure  `blook`->`house`->`room`
where each room has some data and a specific status `red`, `blue`, `green`, `empty`.

I have to iterate through the tree and and display the most common color on each `level`.

Is there an algorithm similar to BinaryMask  to assign a numeric value to each color, 
and  store there "sum" as a single integer and at any time to be able to extract the most common color from the sum?

(if some of the colors have equal counts the priority `red > blue > green`  is taken)

Comment: Why not use three integers? The added overhead of packing everything into one word will probably make this slow and you only have one third of the bits available to store the count.

Comment: How exactly is your tree defined? Is this a multi-dimensional array or are you using objects? If the former, then a combination of array_column() and array_count_values() could be the easiest solution

Comment: the tree is from arrays.

Answer (score 1):

use an array for that... 
like this,

```
$colors = Array('red' => 0, 'blue' => 0, 'green' => 0, 'empty' => 0);
//assign values
$colors['red'] += 1;
//get maximun
array_keys($colors, max($colors))
```